# Display subscripts and superscripts using conditions on Format

Tags: function-construction, output-formatting

I have a simple function Eps[a,b] that I want to display as a a particular symbol. Currently I have the code:

`Format[Eps[a_, b_]] = Superscript[\[Epsilon], ab]`

However, what I would really like is code that has superscript for Eps[a,b], subscript for Eps[-a,-b] and mixed up/down indices for Eps[a,-b]. How can I put conditions on Format to achieve this?

Edit: To be clear - a and b are abstract indices, not necessarily numbers!

Thanks!

Comment: How should Eps[-1,-2] be displayed?

Comment: @DanielHuber Subscript[\[Epsilon], 12]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Format[eps[arg___]] := Module[
 {sub = Cases[{arg}, _Times | _?Negative, 1]},
  Subsuperscript[ϵ, Row[ToString /@ (-sub)], 
   Row[ToString /@ DeleteCases[{arg}, Alternatives @@ sub]]]]

examples = Tuples[{{a, -a, 1, -1}, {b, -b, 1, -1}}]

(* {{a, b}, {a, -b}, {a, 1}, {a, -1}, {-a, b}, {-a, -b}, {-a, 1}, {-a, -1}, {1, 
  b}, {1, -b}, {1, 1}, {1, -1}, {-1, b}, {-1, -b}, {-1, 1}, {-1, -1}} *)

eps @@@ examples
```

[image]

There can be any number of arguments

```
{eps[], eps[a, -b, c], eps[a, -b, c, -d]}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If `a` is a symbol then one could use

```
Format[eps[a_Symbol]]:=Superscript[ϵ,a];
Format[eps[-a_Symbol]]:=Subscript[ϵ,a];
```

---

**Previous answer where I has assumed `a` is a number.** Why not use a good old `If`-statement?

```
Format[eps[a_]]:=If[a>=0,
     Superscript[ϵ,Abs[a]],
     Subscript[ϵ,Abs[a]]];
```

Another option would be

```
Format[eps[a_/;a>=0]]:=Superscript[ϵ,Abs[a]]
Format[eps[a_/;a<0]]:=Subscript[ϵ,Abs[a]]
```

Comment: Ahh, a is not a number - I really want it to be an abstract index.

Answer (score 2):

E.g.:

```
Format[Eps[a_, b_]] := 
 Which[a < 0 && b < 0, 
  Subscript[\[Epsilon], ToString@Abs@a  ToString@Abs@b], 
  a < 0 && b >= 0, Subsuperscript[\[Epsilon], a, b], a >= 0 && b < 0, 
  Subsuperscript[\[Epsilon], b, a], a >= 0 && b >= 0, 
  Superscript[\[Epsilon], ToString@a  ToString@b]]

Eps[1, 2]
Eps[-1, 2]
Eps[1, -2]
Eps[-1, -2]
```

[image]

Comment: This is a nice answer, but I want it to work with actual indices (i.e. I want Eps[a,b] to display literally with a,b not numbers). Sorry if that wasn't clear!

Answer (score 2):

```
Format[Eps[a_ /; a >= 0, b_?Negative]] := 
  Subsuperscript[\[Epsilon], Abs@b, a];
Format[Eps[a_?Negative, b_ /; b >= 0]] := 
  Subsuperscript[\[Epsilon], Abs@a, b];
Format[Eps[a_ /; a >= 0, b_ /; b >= 0]] := 
 Superscript[\[Epsilon], ToString[a] <> ToString[b]]
Format[Eps[a_?Negative, b_?Negative]] := 
 Subscript[\[Epsilon], ToString[Abs@a] <> ToString[Abs@b]]
```

**Usage**

```
{Eps[-3, -1], Eps[-3, 1], Eps[3, -1], Eps[3, 1], Eps[0, -1], 
 Eps[0, 3], Eps[-1, 0], Eps[1, 0]}
```

$$\left\{\epsilon _{31},\epsilon _{-3}^1,\epsilon _{-1}^3,\epsilon ^{31},\epsilon _1^0,\epsilon ^{03},\epsilon _1^0,\epsilon ^{10}\right\}$$

Comment: This is also a nice answer, but I want it to work with abstract indices (i.e. I want Eps[a,b] to display literally with a,b not numbers). Sorry if that wasn't clear!

Comment: Please include what an "abstract" index looks like to your post.